# Why is Contour Series much slower when using filled mode

Tags: delphi, teechart

I created a TeeChart with two TContourSeries: One with filled set to false and one set to true. Both get exactly the same data and both are not active while feeding the data to them.

When I activate the not filled series it takes less than a second to paint itself. Not so the filled series. It takes at least 10 times longer to draw itself.

Why is that so? I would imagine that the filled series uses the same algorithm as the not filled one and then some sort of flood fill is used. That should not take that long.

Is there a way to speed up painting of the series in filled mode? Data reduction is not an option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm copying the reply from [here](https://www.steema.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17247#p76680).

I'm afraid the filling of the contour series isn't so simple as one could think at a first glance.
We are internally using a TIsoSurface to draw the cells, which makes the process slower.

Some references:

- https://www.steema.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12326
- https://www.steema.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10796
- http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1438